# How to follow links using chai-http

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have an API that accepts an image file as input, uploads it, and returns a permanent link to the uploaded image.

Sample of returned JSON:

```
{ "url": "localhost:3000/public/uploads/1471759901731.jpg" }
```

My test, using mocha and chai-http:

```
it('should upload single valid picture on /pictures POST', function(done) {
  chai.request(app)
    .post('/pictures')
    .attach('picture', fs.readFileSync('test/test_data/banana.png'), 'banana.png')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.json;
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('url');
      // should follow the url, ensure status 200
      // follow res.body.url
      done();
  });
});
```

How can I follow the url to ensure it is valid and returns status 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trial and error, I got this to work.

```
it('should upload single valid picture on /pictures POST', function(done) {
  chai.request(app)
    .post('/pictures')
    .attach('picture', fs.readFileSync('test/test_data/banana.png'), 'banana.png')
    .end(function(err, res) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.json;
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      res.body.should.have.property('url');

      // remove hostname from url
      var pic_url = res.body.url;
      pic_url = pic_url.split('/');
      pic_url = '/' + pic_url.splice(1).join('/');

      // follow the link
      chai.request(app)
        .get(pic_url)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          content_type = res.header['content-type'].split('/')[0];
          (content_type).should.equal('image');
          done();
        });
    });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution. I could not find anyone else nesting a `chai.request(app)` inside a `chai.request(app)`.